# How to clean unformatted price and get smallest price in range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I have a dataframe with  column inputs which is actually a string of price like this:

| input |
| --- |
| USD 5000 |
| $ 5000 |
| 5000USD |
| 5000-9000 |
| 5K |

I want to change all the input into a fixed formatted integer like: **5000**. So, the dataframe will contains two columns (input for unformatted string, output for formatted integer) like this:

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| USD 5000 | 5000 |
| $ 5000 | 5000 |
| 5000USD | 5000 |
| 5000-9000 | 5000 |
| 5K | 5000 |

I think its can be done with regex, but I don't know how to do it. I don't have enough experience with regex function. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for actually depends on the data, based on the data sample you have provided, you can first split the values on `-`, then take out the first value from splitted string, then replace `K` by `000` and finally use `str.extract` to filter out non-digit characters.

```py
df['input'].str.split('-').str[0].str.replace('K', '000').str.extract('(\d+)')
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
      0
0  5000
1  5000
2  5000
3  5000
4  5000
```

**EDIT**: As suggested in the comment by [@Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3279716/alex), you can type cast the values to `integer` using `.astype(int)` at the end of the expression:

```
df['input'].str.split('-').str[0].str.replace('K', '000').str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
```

Comment: Really nice answer! Should probably convert that to a number too